# BeautifulSoup, access css value | <div style="background:url('this_one')">

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have

```
<div style="background:url('link_to_img')"></div>
```

and I need to extract an image link of this div, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with regular expressions.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''<div style="background:url('link_to_img')"></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

print(re.search(r'\((.*?)\)',soup.find('div')['style']).group(1))
```

The result is

```
'link_to_img'
```